# Selenium Webdriver and IP Spoofing vulnerability?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

You start webdriver `webdriver-manager start` which opens the port 4444.

Some rogue crawler sees the port is available and start abusing your Selenium Webdriver to work as a IP Spoofing mechanism for their XSS attacks.

Question:

Is there any flag for not making this port publicly available?

Or a configuration elsewhere to simple block outside connections to this specific port?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with selenium, it's not about programming, but rather about iptables/firewall configuration. Also the answer depends on type of OS and firewall used.

Comment: @KirilS. yes it could be solved by IPTables, but all other Selenium Webdriver instances would be exploitable... so there must be a flag somewhere...

Comment: Flag doing what? Let's say if selenium is your line of defense against unauthorized outside connections on any port in your environment, regardless of who's listening on it, you have a bigger problem. I'm not saying webdriver-manager should not have any security features, but if it was managing network layer, that would be weird.

Comment: @KirilS. a flag for accepting only local / internal queries, and blocking external ones. The default of "anyone can use" is quite odd... which I thought of maybe a flag for webdriver somewhere...